# Where command in raster calculator Arcgis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator

I have two rasters that I wish to combine to give a third raster that describes spatially where multiple conditions of both rasters are met. For example, say my two input rasters are raster A and raster B. Values like this:

RASTER A:

```
   X1 X2 X3
Y1 A1 A2 A2
Y2 A1 A1 A1
Y3 A1 A1 A2
```

RASTER B:

```
   X1 X2 X3
Y1 B1 B1 B1
Y2 B1 B1 B1
Y3 B1 B1 B1
```

I want to create a third raster with different values that occur where conditions from both are met, see the below "psuedo-code" describing what I want:

WHERE (RASTERA = A1 AND RASTERB = B1) THEN ALPHA
WHERE (RASTERA = A2 AND RASTERB = B1) THEN BETA

Giving my final raster as below:

```
   X1    X2    X3
Y1 ALPHA BETA  BETA
Y2 ALPHA ALPHA ALPHA
Y3 ALPHA ALPHA BETA
```

How can I accomplish this, preferably using raster calculator?

P.S. In my real data, I have numbers that I need to be in certain ranges. As such I could not simply concatenate the raster values (e.g. A1, and B1 to give A1B1) and give an alias fitting to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the conditional tool where you can use

`Con(((Raster1=a1) &(Raster2=b1)),alpha,Con(((Raster1=a2)&(Raster2=b2)),beta,delta))`

the cells that are assigned 'delta' will be the ones that do not fulfill both conditions given above.